# populate table using XML document - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a XML that i need to fill in to a data grid on ASP.net. single record of the xml is shown below.

```
<environments>
<environment>
  <id>1168</id>
  <name>Application name 1</name>
  <track>version 1</track>
  <market>CORE</market>
  <site>kandy</site>
  <path>c:\Driver</path>
  <template>Environment-v1</template>
  <dbhost>hostName</dbhost>
  <dbvendor>Oracle</dbvendor>
  <dbversion>11.2.0.3.0</dbversion>
  <archives>
    <archive>
        <name>111.222</name>
        <status>Error</status>
        <timestamp>2014-06-05T18:38:55.2920573Z</timestamp>
        <revision>0</revision>
        <dbsize>0</dbsize>
     </archive>
     <archive>
        <name>222.333</name>
        <status>Error</status>
        <timestamp>2014-06-10T17:31:38.7417373Z</timestamp>
        <revision>0</revision>
        <dbsize>0</dbsize>
     </archive>
  </archives>
 </environment>
</environments>
```

i need to fill the data in to the table as like follow. 
[image]

i can fill all the fist 3 fields by adding xml as the data source but my question is how i can populate the drop down using the same xmls `"<archive>"` names.

I need your kind help to sort out the problem.

Comment: Dropdown can also be bound to a data source

Comment: how to do that ? that's my problem actually

Comment: Is your drop down an asp.net control or html control ?

Comment: it is an asp control